# Android: java.lang.IllegalAccessException when attempting to use a custom "Application" class

Tags: android

I'm trying to create define a custom Application class as follows:

1. create an empty subclass of
   Application called MyApp
2. in the manifest, specify
   android::name for my application: 
   `<application android:name=".MyApp"
   ...`

However, when I attempt to run my app, I get:
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.test.MyApp java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to class not allowed`

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Make sure your custom class is `public`, has a `public` zero-argument constructor, and that the constructor chains to the superclass' constructor.

Comment: I came across a similar exception where I was trying to start a service.  It turned out that the service class was accidentally package private and thus your solution helped me find the problem, thanks!

Comment: @CommonsWare not really a constructor, because we (devs) don' instantiate Framework components. Rather a `onCreate()` method.

Comment: @MichałDobiDobrzański: One of the possible causes of "Unable to instantiate" a component is because the class does not have a `public` zero-argument constructor. By default, a class will have one, if you have no other constructors. But, if you define any constructor, you lose the default `public` zero-argument constructor. I agree that most likely you do not need a custom constructor on an `Application` subclass, but that does not stop you from defining one. I was attempting to address the concern from the question, 11+ years ago when it was asked. Sorry if I phrased, my answer poorly!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with CommonsWare. If you extend android.app.Application to define custom application for your project, make sure that you have marked your class as public and public no-agrs constructor as well.

However, on [android.app.Application API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) its mentioned that, **There is normally no need to subclass Application. In most situation, static singletons can provide the same functionality in a more modular way.**

Hope this will help.

Cheers.