# Thread runtime exception

Tags: android

```
synchronized (this.childrenGroupsLock) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numGroups; i++) {
                suspendCurrent |= this.childrenGroups[i].suspendHelper();
            }
        }
return suspendCurrent;
```

This is the thread that force closes my application(any android application). I dunno how to handle it.

Can anyone please help me?

The application just force closes after it reaches this point.

```
05-12 10:22:28.582: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-12 10:22:28.582: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.android/com.android.GraphicsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to class not allowed
05-12 10:22:28.582: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1544)
05-12 10:22:28.582: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
05-12 10:22:28.582: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-12 10:22:28.582: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
05-12 10:22:28.582: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-12 10:22:28.582: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-12 10:22:28.582: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
05-12 10:22:28.582: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 10:22:28.582: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-12 10:22:28.582: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-12 10:22:28.582: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-12 10:22:28.582: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-12 10:22:28.582: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to class not allowed
05-12 10:22:28.582: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
05-12 10:22:28.582: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
05-12 10:22:28.582: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
05-12 10:22:28.582: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(352):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1536)
```

This is the error I am getting in the LogCat

Comment: please show the error that you are getting from Logcat .Open DDMS and get it from there .

Comment: I have edited the prev post and noted the error presented in the LogCat

Comment: This might help you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278091/android-java-lang-illegalaccessexception-when-attempting-to-use-a-custom-applic

Comment: It doesn't seem that the code you posted have anything in common with the exception.. Is `GraphicsActivity` your own class?

Comment: Yes..Its my own class..It should have nth to do with the error, cause I am gettin the same error for every application.

Comment: @Khush did you check the comment by @MByD? Is that the case?

Comment: Yes i did..And it kinda helped. Now the error shown is in the Looper.java(inbuilt class) file. It keeps on looping there and finally terminates. The application does not force close now.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.android.ddmlib.Client.sendAndConsume(Client.java:572)
 at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHELO(HandleHello.java:142)
 at com.android.ddmlib.HandleHello.sendHelloCommands(HandleHello.java:65)
 at com.android.ddmlib.Client.getJdwpPacket(Client.java:671)
 at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:317)
 at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)